# Examples for derandomization via small sample spaces

Tags: reference-request

People in theoretical computer science stack exchange advises me to ask this question here. I ask the same problem in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46668/examples-for-derandomization-via-small-sample-spaces and if you are interested in answers there, you can go to see it.

I read the book the Probabilistic Method and the lecture note Pseudorandomness to study techniques of derandomization and completed some of exercises.

I'm trying the technique of "Derandomization" for some algorithms, and I find some samples using the derandomization via small sample spaces and feel very interested.

To deepen the impression on derandomization via small sample space, I want to see more papers using that.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Understand. I can't delete the problem there because someone has given a nice answer and I don't have the right to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a survey by Luby and Wigderson: [Pairwise independence and derandomization](https://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/LubyWig2005.pdf).